# Swift For Loop Thread Error

Tags: swift, for-loop

```
func randomroll () {

    var time = arc4random_uniform(10)

   while(time < 5)
   {
    time = arc4random_uniform(10)
   }

   for(var time1 = time; time1>=0; time1--) { //This is where I get the thread error
    ...
   }
 }
```

The error I am getting is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

I am a beginner swift programmer and am sure I am missing something obvious, was hoping for some insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func randomroll() {

    var time = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))

    while(time < 5)
    {
        time = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))
    }

    for time; time >= 0; time-- { //This is where I get thread error
        println(time)
    }
}

randomroll()
```

`time` is an Uint32 and can't be negative. So either don't let it become negative or convert it to an `Int`

Comment: In the OP code, `time` is impossible to be negative.

Comment: `for time; time >= 0; time--` Won't this drop `time` to `-1` at the end?

Comment: Correct, it should be `time > 0`.

Comment: Unless he needs to do something as well if the value is `0`.

Comment: Also, it is possible that type inference for `time1` corrects this to int automatically due to the `--` at the end ;-). I think that's what happened in my playground.